# Magento 1.6.2 Change attributes of multiple products in product grid

Tags: custom-attributes

I added some custom attributes that will be run as a promotion (2x1, 3x1) and now I want to update several products at once.

Is this possible using the product grid in backend? I already modified the visibility of the grid to be able to show the attribute, but would like to avoid edit / save each product.

If not possible by default, what would be the reccommended way to do it?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the product grid you can use the `update attribute` action.

Select the products you want to edit, select `Update attributes` option from the select top right

[image]

And edit whatever attributes you want to edit

[image]

Comment: Thanks, The graphics did helped a lot (as UI is in another language).

Comment: Ah my bad, forgot to switch from Dutch :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the UI language I have in my magento is not english.

Answer (score 0):

You could use product grid's `action` drop down and select `Update Attributes` option for batch updating product's attributes.